Meaning of "got behind with his chrysanthemums" in "The Enemy" by Pearl S. Buck
Here is a paragraph from the story "The Enemy" by Pearl S. Buck:

“You say the man escaped?” the General asked faintly. He had been operated upon a week before, an emergency operation to which Sadao had been called in the night. For twelve hours Sadao had not been sure the General would live. The gall bladder was much involved. Then the old man had begun to breathe deeply again and to demand food. Sadao had not been able to ask about the assassins. So far as he knew they had never come. The servants had returned and Yumi had cleaned the guest room thoroughly and had burned sulphur in it to get the white man’s smell out of it. Nobody said anything. Only the gardener was cross because he had got behind with his chrysanthemums.

What is the meaning of the highlighted sentence? I know
that chrysanthemums are flowers, but what meaning does the author want to convey here? I am unable to understand what "got behind with his chrysanthemums" means.

The phrase "got behind with this chrysanthemums" literally means he had not done as much work taking care of his chrysanthemums as he wanted or expected.
The gardener had been opposed to the idea of taking care of the American from the start:

The old gardener, who was also a house servant, pulled the few hairs on his upper lip.
“The master ought not to heal the wound of this white
man,” he said bluntly to Hana. “The white man ought to
die. First he was shot. Then the sea caught him and
wounded him with her rocks. If the master heals what the
gun did and what the sea did they will take revenge on us.”

Later on, he and the cook even leave because Sadao's decision to take care of the wounded American. The quote in the question comes near the end of the story, after Sadao has helped the American escape. The passage and the paragraphs that follow tell us several things:

The General is not too worried that he didn't send the assassins that were supposed to kill the American.
The servants have returned after the American left.
The guest room has been cleaned so it looks again as if the American had never been there.
"Nobody said anything." In other words, people carry on with their lives as before.

The only exception is the gardener, who seems to blame the American for the delay in his work on his chrysanthemums.
P.S. In 1946, four years after Pearl S. Buck published "The Enemy", the American anthropologist Ruth Benedict published the famous study The Chrysanthemum and the Sword: Patterns of Japanese Culture. The title expresses Benedict's view that the cultivation of chrysanthemums is just as much part of Japanese culture as the "cult of the sword".

"delay in his on his chrysanthemums" is missing "work", I assume.

@hobbs Thanks. That's what I meant to write, but the word was lost in rewrites.
